# Replace limited values from a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*Edit*

How would I replace a specific number of values from a specified column in a DataFrame?

```
# babies born in countries

Date            Country

1992-02-15       USA
1995-05-04       USA
1996-02-12       Canada 
2003-12-17       France
2005-01-11       USA
```

Suppose I have the above data and it turns out that the birth country for the first two birth is wrong, instead of USA it should be Spain, France.

I tried the replace method but it changes the values altogether.

Desired result:

```
# babies born in countries

Date            Country

1992-02-15       Spain
1995-05-04       France
1996-02-12       Canada 
2003-12-17       France
2005-01-11       USA
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To access the first two rows via indexing:

```
df.iloc[0:2, 1] = ['Spain', 'France']
```

Or:

```
df.loc[:2, 'Country'] = ['Spain', 'France']
```

Also if you need to access specific rows:

```
df.loc[[0,1], 'Country'] = ['Spain', 'France']
```